# Html textbox: how to restrict input values to only numbers less than 15

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am wanting to only have input values of 01,02,...,09,10,11,12,..,15 permissible in my text field. Please help the newbie with a sample code on how to achieve this. (not using HTML5 yet)

Comment: why not use a combo box.. :P.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["YourTextBoxID"].value;
var y = parseInt( x  ,  10  )
var i=15;
if (y>i)
  {
  alert("Out of range");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to confirm the value really is a number, and check the minimum value too. (And please don't use error messages like "Out of range" without saying what the range is.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you tagged your question with "regex", the [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) you want is something like this:

```
/^(0[\d]|1[1-5])$/
```

Or if you want to make the initial "0" optional:

```
/^(0?[\d]|1[1-5])$/
```

As far as how you use that, well, if you [show the code you've got so far](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) I can advise how to fit it in...

Answer (score 2):

A Sample, why not allow user to enter only numbers? Try this out

```
 <HTML>
   <HEAD>
     <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
       <!--
         function isNumberKey(evt) ' Allow user to enter only numbers
          {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
             if (((charCode > 47) && (charCode < 58 ) ) || (charCode == 8))
                   return true;

              return false;            
          }

          function isless() ' do not submit if greater than 15
           {
             var num = document.getElementById('num_txt').value
             var y  = parseInt( num  ,  10  ) 
             if ( y > 15 )
              return false;

           }

        //-->
     </SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
   <FORM onsubmit="isless()" action="some.php">
   <INPUT  id="num_txt" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" >
   </FORM>
   </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Comment: What if the user enters non-numeric data via drag'n'drop or from the clipboard?

Comment: @nnnnnn thats great never thought of it So my answer has a limitation Thanks for your comment

Comment: @nnnnnn Updated the answer I Guess this should overcome the limitation right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use comboBox.. some code to get started :

```
<select >
<option> 01 </option>
<option> 02 </option>
</select>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices. Users who use a keyboard like to enter text manually so for them it is best to put a hint on the screen that the input should have a value from '01' to '15'. Let the user enter whatever they want and validate it when the form is submitted.

Another option is to use a select element with the values you want, or a sequence of radio buttons. It all depends on your users, the data you are collecting (e.g. dates, counts, ages, whatever).

So find out what your users would like, then implement it. Client side validation is all about making life better for the user, it is not a way of forcing them to do what you want—that's what server side validation is for. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat brittle, but complete solution for this:

In this case, you'd have a text input with an id of test:

`<input type="text" id="test"/>`

Here's your script:

```
var numbers = [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57];

$("#test").bind("keyup",function(e){
    var num = numbers.indexOf(e.which),
        t = $(e.target),
        v = t.val(),
        len = v.length;
    if(len > 2){
        t.val(v.match(/(.+?).$/)[1]);
    } else {
        if(v[0] == 1){
            if(v[1] && v[1] > 5){
                t.val(15);
            }
        } else if(v[0] != 0) {
            t.val("");
        }
    }
});
```

basically, I assign the key codes of all letters to corresponding indices of an array.

Then, on each key down, we figure out what key it is, and if it's in position 0, check if it's 0 or 1.

if it's in position 1, check if it's greater than 5 as long as the first number is 1.

Comment: Thanks to all of u guys for responses.Select list is not an option(wud have been easy for me too). Thanks Jes, this is close to one i was looking for. However, I dont want to allow alpha chars in the input, only allow numbers. Can you please help me achieve it in this code. Thanks again.

Comment: This will not allow any input that isn't a digit - you'll be able to type it, but it will be deleted as soon as you release the key. So it already should work for your purposes. Try the jsfiddle out to see how it works!

Comment: Note that the user can still enter invalid data via the Edit menu or drag'n'drop.